Prove equivalence of definitions of statistical distance
Let $P$ and $Q$ be two distributions over a finite set $U$.
Given I already proved the following definitions are equilivant:
$$
SD(P, Q) = \underset{S⊆U}{max} \ \left\{ \underset{x←P}{Pr} [x ∈ S] − \underset{x←Q}{Pr}[x ∈ S] \right\}
$$
$$
SD(P,Q) = \frac{1}2 \sum_{u\in U}|P(u)-Q(u)|
$$
I need to prove the following definition:
$$
SD(P, Q) = \underset{D}{max}\ \left\{ \underset{x←P}{Pr} [D(x) = 1] − \underset{x←Q}{Pr}[D(x) = 1] \right\}
$$
where $D$ is taken over all deterministic algorithms.

Hint: It is easy to show that the first definition and third definition are equivalent if you consider deterministic algorithm $D$ as a function from $U$ to ${0,1}$ and $x \in S$ as a function that outputs 1 if $x$ is in the set $S$, otherwise it outputs 0.

I think in Victor Shoup book A Computational Introduction to Number Theory and Algebra (Version 2) there are some lemmas and explanations.
